# How to set InputSelect @bind-Value to the current row in a loop?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, webassembly

I have an `IEnumerable<Model> MyModel` which is used with a for each loop to go over each element in the list and create an `<InputSelect>`, within the `<InputSelect>` I am using a for loop to iterate over `MyModel.Count()` to add the `<option>` to the `<InputSelect>`.

```
<EditForm Model="MyModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
            <div class="table-responsive-lg" data-simplebar style="max-height: 300px">
                <table class="table table-centered mb-0 font-14">
                    <thead class="table-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="d-table-cell" style="cursor: pointer">Details (Item Name) Old</th>
                            <th class="d-table-cell" style="cursor: pointer">Details (Item Name) New</th>
                            <th class="d-table-cell" style="cursor: pointer">Quantity Old</th>
                            <th class="d-table-cell" style="cursor: pointer">Quantity New</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
        
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach (var model in MyModel)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            
                            <!--- Current Item Name, followed by Dropdown for potential change. --->
                            <td class="d-table-cell">@(model?.Item?.ItemName ?? "-")</td>
                            
                            <!--- This works fine as the Item Name's are all unique. --->
                            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@model.Item.ItemName" class="form-select">
                                @for (int i = 0; i < MyModel.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    <option value="@MyModel.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Item?.ItemName">@MyModel.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Item?.ItemName</option>
                                }
                            </InputSelect>
                            
                            <!--- Current Quantity Value, followed by Dropdown for potential change. --->
                            <td class="d-table-cell">@(model?.Quantity.ToString() ?? "-")</td>
                            
                            <!--- This does not work as some Quantity values are the same. --->
                            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@model.Quantity" class="form-select">
                                @for (int i = 0; i < MyModel.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    <option value="@MyModel.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Quantity">@MyModel.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Quantity</option>
                                }
                            </InputSelect>
                        </tr>
                    }           
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
</EditForm>
```

The problem is on the second `<InputSelect>` for the Quantity if there are multiple values that are the same i.e. 50 if I change the Quantity on row one from a 50 to 12, this change in value will happen for every row that has a Quantity of 50. Ideally, only the value of the selected row would change.

The documentation for the `<InputSelect>` is quite sparse but if anyone has some detailed documentation to point my way that would be appreciated. I have included two images below of what is happening to help visualise this, if anyone can see where I am going wrong any help would be great.

[image: Quantity before changing the top value to 12]

[image: Quantity after changing the top value to 12]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @key directive in your InputSelect

```
<InputSelect @key=model @bind-Value="@model.Quantity" class="form-select">
```

Comment: Hey Surinder, thanks for the reply I have tried that and unfortunately not solved the issue, oddly it seems to be if I change the first dropdown then the two below that seem to propagate the change but all others do not, have you come across this behaviour before?

Comment: I think I got it, could you please use foreach for MyModel, instead of for loop 
<!--- This does not work as some Quantity values are the same. --->
                            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@model.Quantity" class="form-select">
                                @for (int i = 0; i < MyModel.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    <option value="@MyModel.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Quantity">@MyModel.ElementAtOrDefault(i)?.Quantity</option>
                                }
                            </InputSelect>

Comment: I did try this and no luck, unfortunately, it's strange how it's only the top item propagating down to the next two but no others... have you seen this behaviour before?